# OSRM giving different results

Tags: open-source-routing-machine

On calling API http://osrm.stackbox.xyz/table/v1/driving/78.4444076,11.6000205;78.5929274,11.5958152, I am getting a 2x2 matrix.

When I put the same coordinates with some more co-ordinates like this: 
http://osrm.stackbox.xyz/table/v1/driving/78.4444076,11.5870854;78.5929274,11.5958941;78.5938641,11.6000205;78.5961901,11.5958152, it gives me expected 4x4 matrix.

The issue is it's giving different distance(durations) matrix for points `78.4444076,11.6000205;78.5929274,11.5958152`

Comment: If you don't provide exact coordinates in both sample it's normal. Second call corrected http://osrm.stackbox.xyz/table/v1/driving/78.4444076,11.6000205;78.5929274,11.5958941;78.5938641,11.6000205;78.5929274,11.5958152
Duration is now OK

Comment: @ThomasG77 can you explain little bit more.

Comment: You say you provide points 78.4444076,11.6000205;78.5929274,11.5958152 but your second URL does not contain them. You use instead points 78.4444076,11.5870854 and 78.5961901,11.5958152 so the results for duration will differ

Comment: Ohh I missed it. don't know why I couldn't see it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those are not the same coordinates. Like ThomasG77 pointed out in the comments, those latitudes are different. If you compare

http://osrm.stackbox.xyz/table/v1/driving/78.4444076,11.6000205;78.5929274,11.5958152

with

http://osrm.stackbox.xyz/table/v1/driving/78.4444076,11.6000205;78.5929274,11.5958152;78.5938641,11.6000205;78.5961901,11.5958152

The distances are the same.